# Rails : Shopify app orders create webhook job not performing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks, orders, shopify-app

I want to log orders data when an order is created in Shopify, my shopify rails app receives web hook data in the webhook controller but the job is not performed. I followed the documentation for the **shopify_app gem (8.2.6)** but it is not working.

Currently I am working on development environment with ngrok tunneling.
This issue is with development & production environment.

**Event Version : 2020-04**

This is the config

```
config.webhooks = [
    {topic: 'customers/create', address: Rails.configuration.business_script_endpoint+'/custom/webhooks/customers_create', format: 'json'},
    {topic: 'checkouts/create', address: Rails.configuration.business_script_endpoint+'/custom/webhooks/checkouts_create', format: 'json'},
    {topic: 'orders/create', address: Rails.configuration.business_script_endpoint+'/custom/webhooks/orders_create', format: 'json'}
]
```

This is the code for web hook controller

```
module ShopifyApp
  class WebhooksController < ActionController::Base
    include ShopifyApp::WebhookVerification

    class ShopifyApp::MissingWebhookJobError < StandardError; end

    def receive
      puts 'Here in webhook receive'
      params.permit!
      job_args = {shop_domain: shop_domain, webhook: webhook_params.to_h}
      webhook_job_klass.perform_later(job_args)
      head :no_content
    end

    private

    def webhook_params
      params.except(:controller, :action, :type)
    end

    def webhook_job_klass
      webhook_job_klass_name.safe_constantize or raise ShopifyApp::MissingWebhookJobError
    end

    def webhook_job_klass_name(type = webhook_type)
      puts [webhook_namespace, "#{type}_job"].compact.join('/') 
      [webhook_namespace, "#{type}_job"].compact.join('/').classify
    end

    def webhook_type
      params[:type]
    end

    def webhook_namespace
      ShopifyApp.configuration.webhook_jobs_namespace
    end
  end
end
```

I can see the puts message **Here in webhook receive**

This is the order create job code

```
class OrdersCreateJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(shop_domain:, webhook:)
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)

    puts 'Order create job started'
  end
end
```

I am unable to get the puts message **Order create job started** as it is not performing the job.

The checkout create web hook is working fine in this case. Other two orders & customers create is not performing.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution for this issue.
When I have change web hook controllers receive functions

`webhook_job_klass.perform_later(job_args)`

with

`webhook_job_klass.perform_now(job_args)`

It is working fine.